# Problems with any graph output in SAS

Tags: graph, fonts, sas

Whatever function I use to generate a graph in SAS, even a simple

```
proc gchart data=data;
vbar hello / type=percent;
run;
```

I get this error

```
ERROR: The PNG driver can not find any fonts.  No output will be created.
ERROR: The PNG driver can not find any fonts.  No output will be created.
ERROR: Physical file does not exist, C:\Windows\Fonts\sasmono.ttf..
WARNING: No output destinations active.
```

Do you have any idea about the error?
Thanks

Comment: Earlier in the code is there `ODS _ALL_ CLOSE` or `ODS LISTING CLOSE` ?  Are there any `ODS GRAPHICS` statements ? If so, what are they ?

Comment: No, there isn't. I think the problem can be related to the configuration file, where FONTSLOC does not point to the right folder, but I don't know hot to change it.

Comment: Which SAS client are you using ? Stand alone SAS, EG or Studio ? If stand alone do you use a start menu item or desktop shortcut icon to start SAS, and what is the Target: of the shortcut properties ?

Comment: Possible this is an issue with the installation, but also possible you have a problem with your system printer if it's not defined.  Don't remember off the top of my head how to fix that, but it's a common root cause when you have font problems.

Comment: What about the SG procedures?

Answer (score 0):

What happens if your run the following in a brand new session with no other settings:

```
proc sgplot data=sashelp.class;
vbar sex / stat=freq;
run;
```

Comment: This work perfectly fine, i get the barplot

Comment: SAS/Graph is outdated, if you can switch to SGPLOT procedures you'll get better quality graphs and no issues. If you want to fix the font issue, contact SAS Tech Support and they can walk you through fixing it. I suspect you forgot to install something during installation. Is this in a brand new installation or a new issue?